# How to add double qoutes to all values inside a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
a <- c(one, two, three)
```

and I need it to become

```
a <- c("one", "two", "three")
```

Is there a way to do this using programming?

Comment: What are `one`, `two` and `three`? If these are not already existing objects, then this example isn't valid R code. Could you give a reproducible example of what you mean? Do you mean you have variables called `one`, `two` and `three` that you already have in a vector?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let is be ```one <- 1, two <- 2, three <- 3```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls()` will return a character vector of the names of all the variables defined in your environment. So if `one`, `two` and `three` are the only variables you've defined then it will give you what you want. You can ensure there is nothing else in your environment by using `rm(list = ls())`.

```r
rm(list = ls()) # clear environment
one <- 1; two <- 2; three <- 3 # assign your variables
a <- ls() # capture variable names
a # inspect output
#> [1] "one"   "three" "two"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>